# How to get notification via email whenever new questions are posted 

Tags: discussion, email-notification

I want to know if there is a way to get mail notifications whenever new questions are posted by other members so that I can also contribute in helping them solve their problems.

Would I need to build some level of reputation to enable such a facility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really think that getting email notifications for **all** questions is a good idea as @Piskvor has already mentioned.

<strike>However, you can get [email notifications for Tag Sets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72448/tag-sets-on-stackexchange-com-now-support-email-notifications) that you are subscribed to.  That may be a more viable solution.  Remember though that tag sets are across *all* Stack Exchange sites.</strike>

For some reason the question I linked to previously has been deleted.

Anyway, it seems that you can now subscribe to all questions or filter them using tags from all or specific sites.

You just need to log in on http://stackexchange.com and click the `tagged questions` tab.

[image]

You can then set up multiple filters with various rules. You can also schedule an email too.

Comment: how can i subscribe to a tag set in stackoverflow.com? and after subscribing how can i enable email notification for that tag set?

Comment: @samar - have you read the question I provided a link to? It explains how to do it within that question.

Comment: Barry, the linked post is dead. Can you substitute the link with an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to do this for every question? According to the data explorer, there's a *lot* of questions coming in every day (e.g. [over 3000 on 2010-12-01](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/748/how-many-questions-have-been-posted-on-2010-12-01) ) - that's *several thousand* e-mails coming at you every day, and I doubt you'd like that.

E-mail is rather unsuitable for this, and I think there's no way to get e-mails for all new questions. You can get mail notifications on specific questions that you answered, but that's about it.

What you can do is to watch the RSS feeds of the tags that interest you, e.g. for the tag `.net`, https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?sort=newest&tagnames=.net

Comment: Actually you are right i do not want a mail notification on each and every mail but for certain set of topics. So are you saying that i cannot get a mail notification on questions posted for a certain topic? Also I am unable to answer questions which are posted but I can only comment. Do i need to build some level of reputation before i can start answering questions? Any tips on how can i increase my reputation to that level?

Comment: that's 10k POSTS not 10k QUESTIONS. Actual # of questions, test for PostTypeId = 1

Comment: @Jeff Atwood♦: Ah, okay, should be fixed now. I'm not really proficient with the Data explorer. 3259 questions then - but IMHO anything above 1000 e-mails a day is beyond the power of a human to process regularly - I'm struggling anywhere above 300.