# Is there a way of sending me e-mail compilations of questions?

Tags: support, email-notification

Similar to [Google Alerts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Alerts), I want to have "agents" that e-mail me compilations of questions asked for a given time period (e.g., one day), containing specific keywords.  Is there a way to do this right now with Stack Overflow?

I did find a question similar, but the link on how to subscribe to tags was broken ([how to get mail notification whenever new questions are posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72767/how-to-get-mail-notification-whenever-new-questions-are-posted)).  Is [RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) the only way?

Answer (score 6):

Hover over a tag you want and click subscribe.  This will set up email notifications, configurable to 15 minutes, 3 hours, or daily.  You can manage your existing notifications [here](https://stackexchange.com/filters).

Comment: Awesome.  How did you get to that page, I didn't see it from my account page?

Comment: I got to that link from the confirmation email you get when you first subscribe to a tag.

Comment: Sorry, I figured out the first question & edited it while you were replying.  For multiple tags, there is an "Add Rule" button, so I can add multiple tags to filter by.  I don't know if these are exclusive or inclusive, though.

Comment: Note for posterity: Subscribing to tags no longer sends you email notifications; it just highlights questions with those tags on the site. (You can also use custom filters to find questions with your watched tags that optionally meet other criteria as well.)

Comment: The corresponding tag info contains a reasonable description of tag filters: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-filters/info - using filters one can created an email notification. Tag filters are mentioned also in answers to some related questions, such as: [Subscribe to tags I am interested in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93054) or 
[Email notifications for new questions matching specific tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25224). (But, as pointed out by @V2Blast - some of the information posted there is now outdated.)