# How can I get mail from Stack Overflow on questions about specific technologies?

Tags: support, email, subscription

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get mail notification whenever new questions are posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72767/how-to-get-mail-notification-whenever-new-questions-are-posted)

I want to participate in any newly-posted questions. How can I be notified of newly-posted questions based on Java technologies and UI technologies?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hover on any tag, information will be popout, click on subscribe.

[image]

Comment: I'd upvote this answer, but then I'll spoil the recursive 0 vote count, and that would be a shame

Comment: Nope, someone alraedy did that. Oh well. +1

Answer (score 4):

I'd use some RSS reader and subscribe to

```
http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=java&sort=newest
```

Or subscribe to a tag and you'll get emails as Harry Joy suggested