# On StackOverflow, how to get newest questions for specific tags?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RSS feed of your favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/rss-feed-of-your-favorite-tags)

I am starting to be more involved in stackoverflow ;)
I just want to view where i can see the newest questions that match my favourite tags.
Is it possible?

Comment: ^ I went looking for a feature request and discovered that this feature already exists. (Well, it's for all favourite tags across-the-network, but in your case that's equivalent.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a bookmark like:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python or django?sort=newest
```

Replacing `python or django` with an `or` separated list of the tags you want to watch. Go to that page, and websockets will take care up updating it when new questions are posted.

Comment: Thanks! That's not really integrated with my favourite tags, but at least I have a way to do ti now!

Answer (score 0):

Just click on a tag, then click on `newest`, btw this belongs in meta

Comment: Sorry, I need to see several tags.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can do as said by [Doboy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/185547/doboy):

> Just click on a tag, then click on **newest**.

2. You can also use Favorite and ignore tag features to highlight specific tags question.
3. You can also subscribe to tag as described in here: [How can I get mail from Stack Overflow on questions about specific technologies?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115106/how-can-i-get-mail-from-stack-overflow-on-questions-about-specific-technologies/115107#115107)

Answer (score 0):

Just click on a tag, then click on newest

or

Type the tag name in the search box above and Enter